# Specialize template for any vector<any_arithmetic_data_type>

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I have got a template method with two specialized versions for type `bool` and `vector<string>`.

**Base version:**

```
template <class T> 
const T InternGetValue(const std::string& pfad) const
{
  ...   
}
```

**Specialized versions:**

```
template <>
const bool InternGetValue(const std::string& pfad) const
{
  ...
}  

template <>
const std::vector<std::string> InternGetValue< std::vector<std::string>>(const std::string& pfad) const
{
...
}
```

---

Now I would like to implement *one* specialization that will accept all types of `vector<aritmethic_data_type>` like `vector<double>` `vector<int>` or `vector<float>`.

I could achieve this by writing overloads for the above types, but I'm interested in reaching my goal with another specialization.

This is what I tried so far (leads to error 'illegal use of explicit template arguments'):

```
template <class T>
const std::vector<T> InternGetValue< std::vector<T>>(const std::string& pfad, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_arithmetic<T>>::type* dummy = 0) const
{
}
```

Comment: Fully specialising function templates is rarely useful. What's wrong with the overload approach?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: There's certainly nothing wrong with the overload approach. I'm just being curious how to solve it with specialization. Broaden my horizon... :-)

Comment: Fair enough. As long as you have all the facts. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `std::enable_if` and `std::is_integral` together can solve this problem:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type> 
f(const std::string& d);
```

If `std::` doesn't have them, then use `boost::` if you can. It has them.

Comment: There seems to be a small typo in your example:`enable_if<std::is_integral<T>>, T>` should be right. But there is another compile error after the correction: `ambiguous call to overload function`. I guess the template method you provided clashes with my specialization for `vector<string>`?

Comment: I also don't understand your usage of `enable_if` inside the declaration of the `vector` return value. What is a `vector<true_type/false_type, T>? Could you explain it?

Comment: @nabulke: Sorry, it had to be `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type`. Corrected.

Comment: Sorry, number of <> doesn't match in your example. Won't compile. Should it be `<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T> >::type`?

Comment: @nabulke: That is typo. Anyway, it should be *std::vector< **typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type** >* .... that is, `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type` is the type argument to `std::vector`.

Comment: If you want to use Boost, beware that the replacement for `std::enable_if` is not `boost::enable_if` but `boost::enable_if_c`. Or you can use `boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, T>` (without `::value`). I wish both versions would have been included in the standard...

Comment: @LucTouraille: Good point. In fact, initially I had written this without `::value` part, as I'm more familiar with `boost::` than with `std::`, and thought, it is same with `std::` as well.

Answer (score 5):

OK uber complicated, but I got it all working. I couldn't just check `is_integral` on the `value_type` type inside the first (default) function overload as this would cause SFINAE to remove the overload for non-vectors.

Unlike Nawaz's solution, this doesn't require a dummy parameter to be added, but it does require an enable_if condition on the default function template.

This works on VS2010.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> struct is_vector { static const bool value = false; };
template <typename T> struct is_vector< std::vector<T> > { static const bool value = true; };

// metafunction to extract what type a vector is specialised on
// vector_type<vector<T>>::type == T
template <class T>
struct vector_type
{
private:
    template <class T>
    struct ident
    {
        typedef T type;
    };

    template <class C> 
    static ident<C> test(vector<C>);

    static ident<void> test(...);

    typedef decltype(test(T())) vec_type;
public:
    typedef typename vec_type::type type;
};

// default version
template <class T>
const typename enable_if<!is_vector<T>::value || !is_integral<typename vector_type<T>::type>::value, T>::type
InternGetValue(const std::string& pfad)
{
    return T();
}

// bool specialisation
template <>
const bool
InternGetValue<bool>(const std::string& pfad)
{
    return true;
}

// vector<string> specialisation
template <>
const vector<string>
InternGetValue<vector<string>>(const std::string& pfad)
{
    return vector<string>();
}

// vector<T> specialisation (where T is integral)
template <class T>
const typename enable_if<is_vector<T>::value && is_integral<typename vector_type<T>::type>::value, T>::type
InternGetValue(const std::string& pfad)
{
    return T();
}

int main()
{
    string x;
    auto a = InternGetValue<int>(x);
    auto b = InternGetValue<bool>(x);
    auto c = InternGetValue<vector<string>>(x);
    auto d = InternGetValue<vector<pair<int, int>>>(x);
    auto e = InternGetValue<vector<int>>(x);
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but are you sure SFINAE is necessary to test if something is a vector? Wouldn't something along these lines be sufficient? `template <typename T> struct is_vector { static const bool value = false; }; template <typename T> struct is_vector< std::vector<T> > { static const bool value = true; };`

Comment: And to access the type of the values contained in a vector, you can use `::value_type`: `std::vector<T>::value_type == T`.

Comment: For is_vector, you're absolutely right! That's much simpler. For the vector_type, though, I couldn't get the very first (default) function to specialise that way for non-vectors. If you substitute `typename T::value_type` for `typename vector_type<T>::type`, SFINAE will prevent that overload from being generated for non-vector's.

Comment: Updated my answer with the much simpler is_vector metafunction

Comment: Indeed, accessing `value_type` can be a problem when the type is not a `vector`. Perhaps the best would be to define a metafunction `is_vector_of_integral`, or even better, `is_vector_of`: `template <typename Type, template <typename> class Predicate>
struct is_vector_of
{
    static const bool value = false;
};
 
template <typename ValueType, template <typename> class Predicate>
struct is_vector_of< std::vector<ValueType>, Predicate > : Predicate<ValueType> {};`. This can be used like this: `is_vector_of<std::vector<int>, std::is_integral>::value`.